# I can not display the data from my json_encode ($.each)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Hello to every one and thank you for your time.
My problem is that i can not display the `json_encode` from my php database but in my chrome the data is appear.
The `$.each` is not dispaly all only one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeo1y.jpg)

[image]

now the code for the php :

comment.php

```
$data = $_REQUEST;
$photo_id =38;//$data['photo_id_comment'];
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','gallery');

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM comments";
$sql .= " WHERE photo_id = " . $database->escape_string($photo_id);
$sql .= " ORDER  BY photo_id ASC";

$result = mysqli_query( $con,$sql);

$arr = array();
$row_count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($arr , $row);
}


mysqli_close($con);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

And the ajax to retrieve data is: `script.js`

```
function refreshComment() {

requestData = $("#photo_id_comment").serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/udemy/app_php/includes/comment.php",
    type: "get",
    data: requestData,
    dataType: "text",
    success : function (data) {
        jQuery.each(data, function(index, item) {
            //now you can access properties using dot notation
            $('#chat_box').val( $('#chat_box').val() + item.body + '\n');
            /* $('#author_comment').html(item.author);
            $('#chat_box').html(item.body);*/
        });
    },
    error: function (http, status, error) {
        alert('Some error occurred :'+error);
    }
});

    return false;
}

setInterval( refreshComment , 5000 );
```

And the html where the data is not display is: `photo.php`.

```
 <div class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                    <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">

                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 id="author_comment"  class="media-heading"></h4>
                    <p id="chat_box"></p>
                    <p class="text-info">This is post at: </p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Can you add a small example of your JSON?

Comment: `
0
:
{0: "2", 1: "38", 2: "orfeas", 3: "ela re mlk", 4: "2017-07-03 16:08:36", id: "2", photo_id: "38",…}
0
:
"2"
1
:
"38"
2
:
"orfeas"
3
:
"ela re mlk"
4
:
"2017-07-03 16:08:36"
author
:
"orfeas"
body
:
"ela re mlk"
date
:
"2017-07-03 16:08:36"
id
:
"2"
photo_id
:
"38"
1
:
{0: "3", 1: "38", 2: "lida", 3: "ela re mlk", 4: "2017-07-03 16:12:57", id: "3", photo_id: "38",…}
2
:
`

Comment: jQuery.each is for iterating over DOM objects. To loop through the data youwill need to use a ```for``` or ```while``` loop.

Comment: @evolutionxbox you can see my image above.

Comment: @erevos13 please move this comment into your question?

Comment: I did try the `dataType: 'json'` but still is not display all the data only one. @JaromandaX

Comment: @JaromandaX i insert an image to see the data that came.

Comment: @JaromandaX what do you would like to see?

Answer (score 1):

change `dataType:text` to `dataType:JSON`

**EDIT**

use this instead of `$.each`

```
for(var i = 0;i < data.length ; i++)
{
/*access data as data[i].orfeas*/
}
```

**PHP**

```
  $array = array(); 
  $i = 0;`

 foreach($res as $r){
   $array[$i] = $r;
  $i++;
 }  

header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

EDIT2

USE Header to help jQuery to identify the response type and then jQuery will parse the JSON and you can access it by using a loop above mentioned

Comment: Is this the whole answer? Or just a suggestion?

Comment: @Kunal  i did and that an still display only the first , the `$.each ` is not working

Comment: @evolutionxbox got to be both Xd

Comment: See my comment above. Your ```jQuery.each``` will NOT loop through the data.

Comment: YEAH  ! you are right and then @erevos13 can  use data.index to access the value. but this only possible when dataType is set to JSON because jQuery will parse the json automatically and can be accessed from a for or while.

Comment: @SloanThrasher i did and that i do not get it , only display the last data from the `json`

Comment: EDITED MY ANSWER .

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one,

```
$sql  = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE photo_id = " . $database->escape_string($photo_id) ORDER  BY photo_id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query( $con,$sql);
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

and change ,

```
dataType:'json' instead of dataType:'text'
```

in script.

Comment: I try and that but they display only one of my data. @Renu

Comment: try this one, while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) @erevos13

Answer (score 0):

in your script.js file make change on success function of ajax:-

```
 success : function (data) { 
    $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(key,item){
           $('#chat_box').val( $('#chat_box').val() + item.body + '\n');
      });
  }
```

Comment: for p tag dont use $('#chat_box').val(). use this $('#chat_box').innerHtml()